# IdentityServer Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header

Tags: identity-server

I have a strange issue with IdentityServer,
during redirect to IS, I see an 500 and in logs:

```
2022-12-08T00:04:31.7333120+00:00 [INF] (Sitecore Identity/xxxx) Route matched with "{action = \"Login\", controller = \"Account\"}". Executing controller action with signature "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] Login(System.String)" on controller "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController" ("Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer").
2022-12-08T00:04:31.7351761+00:00 [INF] (Sitecore Identity/xxxxx) Executing action method "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Login (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)" - Validation state: Valid
2022-12-08T00:04:31.7446769+00:00 [INF] (Sitecore Identity/xxxx) Executed action method "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Login (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)", returned result "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult" in 0.1069ms.
2022-12-08T00:04:31.7461571+00:00 [INF] (Sitecore Identity/xxxx) Executed action "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Login (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)" in 11.7482ms
2022-12-08T00:04:31.7491966+00:00 [ERR] (Sitecore Identity/xxxx) An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x0009
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpHeaders.ThrowInvalidHeaderCharacter(Char ch)
```

what could be an issue with it ?

Comment: Do you have any non-ascii characters on your CM server url?

Comment: @MarekMusielak it looks like my2-some.site.com noting special I checked it seems fine. IS url seems ok as well

Comment: If you look up the code 0x0009 it is HT (Horizontal Tab). So im guessing you might have copied and pasted the user name or password and accidentally copied a tab character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dean were right it was hard to catch char at `AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1`